# R language. Private GitLab. Unable to send userauth-publickey request Error

Tags: r, gitlab

I can successfully access gitlab project using Git Bash or via R-studio with my credentials.

But when I try to install project using devtools it returns error.

Here is my code

```
creds = git2r::cred_ssh_key(publickey = "C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\id_rsa.pub", privatekey = "C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\id_rsa")
devtools::install_git("git@gitlab.mycompany.com:my_project.git",  credentials = creds)
```

Here is log:

```
Downloading git repo git@gitlab.mycompany.com:my_projects/my_project.git
Installation failed: Error in 'git2r_clone': Failed to authenticate SSH session: Unable to send userauth-publickey request
```

I use R-Studio, Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was fixed by recreation of key